# Use array as constructor for array of classes

Tags: java

I've been trying to get this working for far too long. I am to use an array of strings to construct an array of "sentence" classes by using the string as part of the constructor. Can anyone help me out?
    public class FileConverter {

```
private final String input;
private final String output;
private boolean inputEncrypted;
private ArrayList<Sentence> y;

public FileConverter(String input, String output, boolean inputEncrypted) {                
    this.input = input;
    this.output = output;
    this.inputEncrypted = inputEncrypted;
}

// this method creates an array of sentences from input
public boolean readInput() {
    String[] x = input.split("\\.");        

   for(String x1:x){
       Sentence a = new Sentence(x1);
        y.add(a);
   }
    return false;
}
```

y.add(a) is giving me a null pointer exception. I've tried a few different ways to do this and I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: you need to instantiate "y" i.e do this --> private ArrayList<Sentence> y = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: `private ArrayList<Sentence> y = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Instantiate y (private ArrayList<Sentence> y = new ArrayList<Sentence>())

Comment: Hint: try using a search engine the next time. This is a superbasic problem and you would not have needed to spend your time writing up this question...

Comment: After years of programming, you start getting used to this error and feel shame for it happening.

Comment: I tried searching but I guess I didn't know what to search